# How to get the element position with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I am trying to change my sidebar position absolute to fixed. The idea is that the side bar is going to be absolute until it touches the footer, and then it would be fixed. So the code bellow works fine in my big monitor, but on my small monitor, the sidebar becomes fixed before it hits the footer, and I assume on a bigger monitor, the sidebar would run into the footer and the code bellow would not trigger.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 5953) {
        $('.hanger').addClass(' hanger sidebar');
        $('.xoxo').removeClass('xoxo2 ')
        $('.xoxo').css("position", "fixed");
    }
})
```

So is there a way to get the number `5953` dynamically? I have tried:
`var value = $('#footer').scrollTop()` and var value = `$('#footer').offset().top` and then pass the `value` variable instead of the fixed number

Here is the demo http://aurelslab.co.uk/ - if your monitor is bigger or smaller then mine you'll see that the sidebar does not work as it should

Thanks

Comment: The `$('#footer').offset().top` route should work fine and is logical. Is that what your current code is using? On my monitor the example you linked to works OK.

Comment: @Utkanos no I am use the value of 5953 that is why it works for you. where as the offset().top would return 7072 which would not trigger the above condition at all

Comment: @Aurel Can you please tell me at what viewport size you are recieving a 7072 when you expect it to be 5953? I can only get 7072 @ 1024/768, and 5953 is sure not even close to what the # should be at this size.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I am getting at Viewport size: 1267 x 985 and Window size: 1267 x 1080

Comment: @aurel: I have added my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11494604/500725)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this, what you're looking for?

```
var value           = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop(); 
var elementTop      = $('#pagefooter').offset().top;

if( value >= elementTop ) {
    $('.hanger').removeClass('sidebar');
    $('.xoxo').addClass('xoxo xoxo2')
    $('.xoxo').css("position","absolute");  
}
else if( value < elementTop ) {
    $('.hanger').addClass(' hanger sidebar');
    $('.xoxo').removeClass('xoxo2 ')
    $('.xoxo').css("position","fixed");  
}
```

I tested it locally and it seems to work, whatever size your window has. It basically adds the window size to the scrolltop to see, whether the footer has moved into the viewport yet.

#### 2 notes

When scrolling on a mobile device (like with iOS) the scroll event is fired when all momentum has come to an end. So you will not see the smooth movement you see on a desktop.

And the id of your footer is not `footer` but `pagefooter`. :)

Comment: Thank a lot it seems to work in all the situations that was not working before.

Answer (score 0):

To access the footer element, either you can use element id or element.

### Example:

- To access footer element: `$('footer')`
- To access footer id: `$('#pagefooter')`

Just do this, to find the current footer position.

```
var currentPosition = $('footer').position().top - $(window).height();
```

I have prepared a rough **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/kjbLL/2/)** to explain you.